# Why are my laptop sending requests to microsoft ncsi ca every 15 seconds from different ports?

Tags: networking, security, dns, microsoft, packet-analyzer

so I was doing some packet sniffing using wireshark when I noticed that my laptop are consistently sending requests to [www.msftncsi.com](http://www.msftncsi.com), I have no idea why this is happening all of a sudden, this is new behaviour. I've tried tracking down the application using `netstat -ptc` and grepping the output for matching the port last used according to wireshark. However the pid/program name only shows as a dash, leading me deeper into confusion. I've read about expressvpn causing such behaviour for some but should it not show in the name column if this was the case? The only recent program I remember installing aside from expressvpn is virtualbox which I checked with sha256sum before installing.

Any help that can lead me to find out why and from where these requests are being made are welcome. A big part of why I want this solved is to know whether it is nefarious activity or not. Also it just bugs the hell out of me not knowing what is happening.

My knowledge about network analysis is very basic so if anyone has any advice on how to get to the bottom of this I would be grateful.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I am running ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS and are using Mozilla Firefox with the following add-ons,
Addblocker ultimate
Facebook container
Privacy badger

---

It seems like oracle has been using Akami Technologies at least in the past so perhaps this is the source of the weird queries. Any ideas how to go about confirming this? I can't find to much information on google about this, maybe it is not supposed to be public knowledge?

Comment: You haven't provided any OS & release details.  I can't imagine any Ubuntu system sending requests to that address, it'll be something you've added to your system no doubt (what browser do you use? what addons? etc but most importantly what OS & release)

Comment: Doing a whois/DNS lookup on the domain shows it's an edgesuite.net domain which I believe is a content delivery network (CDN) run by Akamai Technologies. On a web page I saw someone said "Oracle uses this for it’s VirtualBox updates" (I am not saying that's a fact) but if true could explain it as you said you installed virtualbox.

Comment: Try `sudo ss -tup | grep "msftncsi\|23.63.28"`

Comment: Akamai is a CDN.  Many providers, Microsoft included, use it.  The fact it's reaching out to "akamai" in no way guarantees that this is a problem.  Further, a common URL going to `msftncsi.com` is to ncsi.txt which is a Plain Text file which is part of Microsoft's Network Connectivity Status Indicator system, and the tests are going out to make sure your network is up to date.  There's multiple NCSI systems, Ubuntu, Microsoft, etc. that all do this.